# Factory method not working: returns parent class instead

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement what I believe is a factory class. I have an API framework. After my front controller has processed the request it attempts to return the output to the client. The call in my front controller looks like this:

```
<?php
...
$response_obj = new Response($response_str, 'json');
echo $response_obj->render();
?>
```

My `Response` class basically takes the second argument as the type of class to instantiate, and passes this new class the contents of `$response_str`. Here it is:

```
<?php
class Response {

    public function __construct($data, $format) {
        switch ($format) {
            case 'json':
                $obj = new ResponseJson($data);
            break;
        }
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

And then my `ResponseJson` class looks as follows:

```
<?php
class ResponseJson {

    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        return $this;
    }

    public function render() {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        return json_encode($this->data);
    }
}
```

However, in my front controller `$response_obj` returns its type as `Response` and not `ResponseJson` as would be expected, and a call to the `render()` method (which exists in `ResponseJson` and not `Response`) throws a Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Response::render() in /Users/Martin/Sites/api-framework/index.php on line 61

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What @Kaii said.  Here's some light reading on PHP patterns.  The first example is a Factory: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you describe is not a factory, but rather invalid code. (the __construct will always return a new instance of the class it is implemented in. in fact, it does not need to return anything because this has no effect!)

A factory is usually implemented as a static function that can be called *without instantiating* an object of the factory class. It then creates an object instance of a class (in most cases of *another* class, as in your case) and returns that.

your Response class should look like this:

```
<?php
class Response {

    static public function create($data, $format) {
        switch ($format) {
            case 'json':
                $obj = new ResponseJson($data);
                break;
            case default:
                return NULL; // or throw exception!
                break;
        }
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

and your frontend controller like this:

```
<?php
...
$response_obj = Response::create($response_str, 'json');
echo $response_obj->render();
?>
```

Comment: I had to wait for Stack Overflow to allow me to accept as you answered so fast! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the factory pattern:

The constructor method is called automatically on the instantiation of the class as an object, as I'm sure you know.

The instantiation of an object will always return the object itself, it defies a lot of logic for the instantiation of an object to return anything other than itself, especially an object of a different type. Because of this rule, the constructor method cannot return, it will always only be called on instantiation and thus return the object itself.

I'm not entirely clear on your context but it seems odd that you want a factory in this circumstance, I would expect ResponseJson to extend Response not be created by it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i guess "json" is just an example, "xml" will be the next logical implementation here. Using a factory makes totally sense. Lets say a consumer of the webservice can specify (e.g. via GET param) in which format it would like the answer. Just pass that preference to the facory and you're done.

Comment: @Kaii Nailed it. The idea is to use a common interface of methods and whatnot to render a response—no matter the format—be it JSON, XML, or whatever.

Comment: +1 for providing the explanation why having __construct() to return anything is senseless which my answer is missing

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to implement a factory pattern, you can do something like:

```
//Pseudo-code
class ResponseFactory
{
    createJSONResponse($data)
    {
        return new JSONResponse($data);
    }

    createXMLResponse($data)
    ...

    createDefaultResponse($data)
    {
        return createJSONResponse($data);
    }
}
```

Although, for response types (of which there will probably only be 2 or 3) I think I'd go with Kaii's static factory method.

In response to your comment, the reason I prefer standard factory, each method looks like the above, rather than:

```
createResponse($type, $data)
{
    if ($type == 'json')
        return new JSONResponse($data);
    else if (...)
        ...
}
```

Especially because in many cases your caller looks like:

```
$response = createResponse('json', $data);
```

I prefer this:

```
$response = createJSONResponse($data)
```

Although I should note that php's ability to call a string as a function can make for a very elegant (though somewhat unsafe) abstract factory.

Comment: This wouldn't be suitable as I'd then have to call the methods like `createJSONResponse` which isn't desirable.

Comment: You can generalize this to produce an abstract factory pattern which would be called like createResponse('JSON', $data). Both patterns have merit, but personally I find the standard factory to be more readable. If you have Response types being added to the factory at runtime then the abstract factory is definitely the way to go.